# ¿Como guardo una consulta SQL en un archivo JSON? NodeJS

Tags: mysql, json, nodejs, express

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que en el servidor debe hacer una consulta SQL, luego mostrarla en pantalla y por ultimo guardarla en un archivo .json, logro hacer que mi código muestre correctamente la información en pantalla pero no que la guarde:

```
router.get('/:nroMatricula', (req, res)=>{
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM matriculas WHERE matricula= ?', [req.params.nroMatricula], (err, rows, fields)=>{
    if(err) throw err;

    const matriculadoJson = res.json(rows);

    res.matriculadoJson;
```

Eh intentado hacer que esa información mostrada se guarde utilizando 'fs':

```
matriculado_json = JSON.stringify(matriculadoJson); //Con esta linea aseguro convertir la información a string

fs.writeFileSync('./source/json/matriculado.json', matriculado_json, 'urf-8'); //Con esta linea se guarda la información dentro de un archivo matriculado.json
```

Pero no funciona, alguna sugerencia para que se guarde correctamente?

Comment: *Pero no funciona* es algo muy amplio. ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Te da algún mensaje de error? ¿Cuál?

Comment: Saludos @MauricioContreras Primeramente no se guardan los datos dentro de matriculado.json.
El segundo lugar el tipo de error es: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'source/json/matriculado.json' sin embargo, la ruta existe.

Comment: En primer lugar, cuando trabajas con `fs`, es preferible usar  rutas absolutas (`/dev/path/project/subfolder`), y tu estás usando una ruta relativa (`./relative/to/something/`). Toma en cuenta que la ruta es relativa al directorio de trabajo actual, y no relativa al directorio donde está el `script`. Tal vez el problema está allí. Te recomiendo que verifiques que realmente la ruta relativa que usas existe en el directorio de trabajo (usualmente el directorio desde el que se ejecuta la aplicación). En segundo lugar, imagino que es un error de tipeo, pero es `utf-8`. Tienes `urf-8`. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Amigo. esto funcionó sin problemas.